# How to define a value of an element of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am not sure the proper way to describe the issue, so I would appreciate help in formulating the question if unclear.

There are two sets of words, set A = {dog,apple,couch...} B = {juice,table,apple...}, and each word has a value associated with it.  For example, in set A, dog = 8, apple = 5, couch = 4, and in set B, juice = 8, table = 5, apple = 4.  These values come from a function, for example f(y) = 2 + 6/x.  The x value is the order of the words in a list.

Since the sets are not ordered (by what I read), I am having a hard time finding a way to notate/explain how to get the values.   On one hand, I can order the words based on the value they have, on the other, I can pair them with their values.

The end goal is to describe that given some word in set A, that words value is added to the same word found in set B value (if it is not found, it is 0).  So for dog, it would be 8+0, and for apple 5+4.

That was just an explanation of the basic, but below is more what im trying to do so the function turned to $s(x)$ is more realistic.

So far, this is where I have gotten with some inspiration from the comment:

$s(x)= \frac{q}{x}$

Where $q$ is the number of words

$sum = \sum\limits_{i\in A\cap B} h(i)$

Where $i$ is the word.

The problem I have now, how do I state $h(i)$ takes in the word, and uses the index of the word in the corresponding set?

With further improvement from @JMoravitz;

Essentially I want to show something like:

$A = \{ x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n: x_i\prec x_j\Leftrightarrow i<j \}$

$B = \{ x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n: x_i\prec x_j\Leftrightarrow i<j \}$

$h(x) = s($index of $ x$ such that $x\in A) + s($index of $x$ such that $x\in B)$

Based on the definition of the set, how to I explicitly reference the $n$ (or $i$?) in $x_n$ or $x_i$

As in: $s(i$, where $i$ is the value of the subscript $i$ in $x_i$ where $x_i \in A$ $)$

Comment: If a set is finite, you may define an order (for example lexicographical order), but avoiding this I would name the function that maps elements from $A$ to a number as $f$ and the function that maps elements from $B$ to a number as $g$ and then define the function $h$ as $h(x)=\begin{cases} f(x)+g(x)&\text{if}~x\in A,~x\in B\\ f(x)&\text{if}~x\in A,~x\notin B\\ g(x)&\text{if}~x\notin A,~ x\in B\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Im not sure I see how this solves the problem, f(x) or g(x) are taking in a word, but that word has no value on its own, meaning f(x) and g(x) have to be defined as well, to be related to the list of word,value pairs, which is where I started to begin with

Comment: Precisely.  "Each word has a value...based on a function", I had assumed you already had defined those functions.  Instead of calling it a "vector" (it wouldn't be), you can call it an ordered set and refer to each words' position in the set (so long as you also define how they are ordered, either manually or using one of the already commonly defined orders such as lecicographic or colexicographic order).  In the end, a function you write will do what you tell it to do.  You just need to tell it to do it.

Comment: @JMoravitz So the order in the set is based on some data, lets say a lookup table, where each word has a frequency in different sets.  For example, newspaper A and newspaper B, the number of times the word shows up in each paper is the order in the set.  Then that index of that set is put through the $\s(x)$ function to get a value.  How can I define the order and relate it to the reason of the order (since its not alphabetical or such)?

Comment: Using words like you just did.  From a mathematical standpoint, that is good enough.  Are you asking how to actually implement this into code?

Comment: @JMoravitz The code is written, I am trying to explain in mathematical notation what I did in the code.  If you are referring to latex code, then yes, I am not sure what symbols are good to use, as long explanations can be more confusing than proper notation that is consistent (I just am lost on finding a good fit).  I was also looking for a something a bit general, so that it would be easier for others to quickly see what is going on instead of piecing together multiple explanations and conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is easiest to simply use the words and phrases you already used above in the comments.  Just because something is "mathematical" doesn't mean that it needs to use symbols.

If you are asking for additional opinions on how to phrase/rephrase the same, here is my understanding of what you want and how I would word it:

Given a set $A=\{word_1,~word_2,~word_3,~\dots,~word_n\}$ and a total order $\prec_A$ on $A$, you may define an order preserving bijection $\sigma$ from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $A$ such that $i<j\Leftrightarrow \sigma(i)\prec_A \sigma(j)$.

For a word in $A$ then, its "position" is $\sigma^{-1}(word)$.  You can then use this value of position in your function $f$ that you defined above.  Doing similarly for $B$ will give you an appropriate $g$, and you can then add these together as I described above in the comments.

While all of this is well and good, it is horribly unnecessary.  When we have a totally ordered finite set, we can choose to write it as $A=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n\}$ where $x_i\prec x_j\Leftrightarrow i<j$.  Since there is only one way to have written it in such a way given a particular order, there is no confusion when referring to $x_2$ as "the second smallest thing in our ordered set."

From a coding standpoint, its as though you have an array with two columns: the first column is for the wordname, and the second column is for whatever statistic you are using to order your set by, and then you ran a sorting algorithm based on the second column.

Comment: This seems to make sense, can the second part be written as $A = \{ x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n: x_i\prec x_j\Leftrightarrow i<j \}$  
Also, could you just clarify, how to define the difference between $h(i)$ and $g(i)$ in the summation so that they are defined in relation to taking in the word as $i$ and that being the $n$ index in each set, which is set to the function $s(x)$ ?  Like $h(x) = s(i)$ where $i \in A,i = n$ where (dont have any idea here...) $n$ is the $n$ of the element $x_n$ in the set $A$ ?